# Flip and reposition the initial state of an object

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I tried to initialize a 3D object, but found it to be skewed initially, and the axis of rotation is in the lower right corner.

If the position of the axis of rotation is not in the center, it will be a little weird when the user rotates to watch it.

I tried to make an auxiliary line to see the state of the object as follows:

```
 private axes() {
    var axes = new THREE.AxesHelper(30);

    this.scene.add(axes);
    var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 30, 0x2C2C2C, 0x888888);
    gridHelper.position.y = -10;
    this.scene.add(gridHelper);
  }
```

[image]

How can I flip a 3D object and reset its center:

[image]

Or can I correct the placement of objects by moving the camera angle?

Comment: You should do this in a 3D editor like blender instead. The object's own model coordinates are screwed. Center and fix those instead.

Comment: I'm not familiar with software like blender, can't I do this with three.js?

Comment: You can do `obj.geometry.center();` first, this will at least put the origin at the model's center. But it won't fix the rotation / skewedness.

Comment: However it's always better to fix what's actually wrong rather than to work around it.

Comment: @ChrisG I hope so too.. but I don't have that ability, the file source I will be using is a public repository.

Comment: Can you give me the link? Maybe I can fix the asset.

Comment: That database needs to go through some verification process to get the files. I only got some test files at the moment, but I found that they all have this problem. Can I ask for your help after getting the official files?

Comment: That verification stay requires my country's electronic certificate card and card reader..

Comment: They all are rotated and off-center...? Maybe I can write a script to fix them. Yes, feel free to contact me

Comment: I'm not sure if all the files have a deviation problem, but the test files I got so far are so.. .Thank you very much, I will reply to this message when the time comes.